# Regex that matches {{ string|trans }}

Tags: php, regex, twig

I have multiple .phtml files and I would like to select all the strings before |trans }}, without {{ before the string.

Like this:

```
{% block title %}{{ 'Detail Hostess:'|trans }} {{ host.Name }}{% endblock %}
```

Now I would like to select `'Detail Hostess:'`. This is the regex that I have now:

```
/\{{2}\s*([^|]+)\|trans\s*\}{2}/i
```

Sometimes it works, but in the case above he selects `'Detail Hostess:'` and 
`host.Name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content`

So how can I fix the regex?

Comment: [Your regex seems to work fine in the above case?](http://regex101.com/r/uM3lD2)

Comment: the `\|trans` should prevent the regex from selecting anything inside {{}} that doesn't end with `|trans }}`...

Comment: Your original RegEx as well as this one `/{{\s*([^|]+)\|\s*trans\s*}}/` matched correctly for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue might be linked to the fact that when you use `[^|]+`, there's nothing to prevent you from going outside of a `{{...}}` construct: your regex will match `host.Name }}{{ 'Detail Hostess:'` in `{{ host.Name }}{{ 'Detail Hostess:'|trans }}`.

If you're sure there can be no `}` in your wanted text, a quick fix would be replacing `[^|]` with `[^|}]`:

```
{{\s*([^|}]+)\|trans\s*}}
```

Btw in PHP no need to escape the `{` if it's not followed by a digit, nor `}` if not preceded by one: see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mI2mI8).

Comment: @nielsv: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it completely solved your issue, and you should update your question as your example isn't really relevant: your regex is actually working for that one...

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine with the default construct, but it is also possible that `|trans` is part of a filter chain, i.e.:
`{{ 'foo'|humanize|trans }}` or `{{ 'foo'|trans|upper }}`, how can I cover this?

Comment: @RalfHertsch Not sure what you want to do exactly... Maybe try to get what you want from `{{([^}]+)\|trans(?:\|([^}]+)|\s*)}}` (http://regex101.com/r/yL7dX5/2) or ask a different question if you need help tweaking it!

Answer (score 0):

I think that having the "|trans" mark, there is no need to check for "|" or "}", you just have to look for "|trans", but using a lazy quantifier.

```
/{{\s*(.+?)\|trans\s*}}/i
```

Test:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4Ly

---

**Edit.** Correction fixing what **Casimir et Hippolyte** says.

The advantage of this solution is that there are not forbidden characters inside the searched string.

**Robin**'s answer may be faster, but the searched string cannot contain "|" or "}" characters.

Comment: This pattern will not work if you have a string like: `{{abc|trans}}{{def|trans}}` the result for the capture group will be: `abc|trans}}{{def` because the quantifier `+` is greedy by default. You can avoid the problem using a lazy quantifier instead: `+?` but it stay slower than a negated character class with a greedy quantifier: `[^|}]+`

Comment: IT also selects too much on `{{ host.Name }}{{ 'Detail Hostess:'|trans }}`: http://regex101.com/r/yL7dX5/1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks at @Robin. This is the expression I'm finally using to parse translation filters in Twig:

```
{{([^}]+)\|(?:transchoice\((.*?)\)|transchoice|trans|trans\((.*?)\))(?:\|([^}]+)|\s*)}}
```

this RegEx covers:

```
{{ 'foo'|trans }}
{{ 'foo %variable%'|trans({'%variable%':'foo'}) }}
{{ 'foo'|humanize|trans }}
{{ 'foo %variable%'|trans({'%variable%':'foo'})|capitalize }}
```

and also all variants with `transchoice`.